# How does GDB know about threads

Tags: multithreading, gdb

I am trying to understand more deeply how GDB knows about threads.

- How is it able to tell which one is the current thread ?
- How does it know all the context information relative to each thread ?

My question aims at how it works internally in GDB, I do not have any problem debugging threads, it is all really about GDB's internals.

I found the [GDB internals documentation](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdbint.html), but the threads part is empty as for now.
All my other research lead me to question about debugging multi-threaded programs and I cannot seem to dig the precise information I am looking for.

Edit :

So far it seems that GDB intercepts signals (thanks to ptrace?) and finds out when threads are created. But I would like to know more precisely how it is actually done.

I also have a particular architecture that comes with a GDB that was configured with --enable-threads=single. That GDB is however able to list the current threads. How is this possible ?

Every knowledge, useful links or documentations are welcomed.

Thanks.

---

**Update March 5 '14**

I have looked into the libthread_db and found out that GDB allows providing a custom built library to debug threads (see [doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) for information)

I have tried to do that and am able to provide gdb information about my thread (ID, start function, stack and such) by implementing the `td_thr_get_info` function defined in `gdb/common/gdb_thread_db.h`.

Still i am not able to give gdb any information about the context of my threads and still looking for any clue on that issue.

Thanks.

PS: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972568/teaching-gdb-to-understand-micro-threads-from-core-files#comment33599283_19972568) seem to address the same questions but has unfortunately no directions too.

Comment: FYI, I am working in a Linux environment, but I'd like to keep the information as much generic as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "current" thread? I would imagine the thread creating routines are intercepted, so GDB finds out about stack and other properties from certain memory locations in the process memory (heap).

Comment: Yes, I came across such assertions during my researchs although I am looking for more precision in how this is actually done in GDB. Studying its source code gives information, but it is quite a wild jungle.
I also edited the question to focus more on the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to search for information about [`libthread_db`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/libthread_005fdb_002eso_002e1-file.html#libthread_005fdb_002eso_002e1-file).